# When adding vectors, check if a vector $E$ is reached at some point.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

For 2 dimensional vectors: $V_1,V_2,...,V_n$

Suppose there is an exclusion vector $\vec{E}$.

In the process of adding these vectors (in any order), you have to check if the exclusion vector $E$ is reached. FOR Example: $[1,1], [2,2], [2,3]$ are my vectors. I have an exclusion vector $E = [3,4].$

There is a combination of adding these vectors that reaches the exclusion vector. $[1,1] +[2,3]+[2,2]$.  Adding the first 2 yields $[3,4]$.

Now, of course, you could brute force all the combinations and check these.

But I am looking for an analytical method which can solve this problem. The input is $n$ vectors, and an exclusion $E$ and it can tell me if it is reached or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat more efficient than brute-force:  Let $B_m$ be the set of vectors that can be
obtained as the sum of a subset of $V_1, \ldots, V_m$.  Compute iteratively using
$B_0 = \{0\}$ and $B_{m+1} = B_m \cup \{V + V_m: V \in B_m\}$, until either you find
$E$ or get to $B_n$ without finding it.

Alternatively: if $V_i = [a_i, b_i]$ and $E = [c,d]$, form the "generating function" $\prod_{i=1}^n (1 + x^{a_i} y^{b_i})$ and check if the coefficient of
$x^c y^d$ is nonzero.

I don't think you can do much better than these.  The one-dimensional version of your problem is the Subset Sum Problem, which is NP-complete.